# Build of RPM Patch Fails

Tags: rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am building a custom RPM Patch of " nfs-utils-lib-1.0.8 " to include the latest ' librpcsecgss-0.19 ' patch. Here are my steps:

1. rpm -ivh nfs-utils-lib-1.0.8-7.9.el5.src.rpm
2. rpm -bp nfs-utils-lib.spec
3. cp -r nfs-utils-lib-1.0.8 nfs-utils-lib-1.0.8.orig
4. Download the latest " librpcsecgss-0.19.tar.gz " to the SOURCE directory from:
5. http://www.citi.umich.edu/projects/nfsv4/linux/librpcsecgss
6. Navigate to: BUILD/nfs-utils-lib-1.0.8/librpcsecgss/src/ and delete ' svc_auth_gss.c '
7. Then get the latest ' svc_auth_gss.c ' from librpcsecgss-0.19.tar.gz downloaded in step 4.
8. diff -Naur nfs-utils-lib-1.0.8.orig/ nfs-utils-lib-1.0.8 > ../SOURCES/librpcsecgss-0.19-bufoverflow.patch
9. I work on my spec file now below:

nfs-utils-lib.spec

```
Summary: Network File System Support Library
Name: nfs-utils-lib
Version: 1.0.9
Release: 8.0%{?dist}
URL: http://www.citi.umich.edu/projects/nfsv4/linux/
License: GPL

%define idmapvers 0.21
%define libnfsidmap libnfsidmap
%define rpcsecgssvers 0.19
%define librpcsecgss librpcsecgss
%define libs %{librpcsecgss} %{libnfsidmap}
Source0: http://www.citi.umich.edu/projects/nfsv4/linux/libnfsidmap/%{libnfsidmap}-%{idmapvers}.tar.gz
Source1: http://www.citi.umich.edu/projects/nfsv4/linux/librpcsecgss/%{librpcsecgss}-%{rpcsecgssvers}.tar.gz

Patch0: librpcsecgss-0.13-compile.patch
Patch1: libnfsidmap-0.21-compile.patch
Patch2: librpcsecgss-0.14-bufoverflow.patch
Patch3: nfs-utils-lib-changelicensetoBSD.patch
Patch4: libnfsidmap-0.21-idmapdconf-man.patch
Patch5: libnfsidmap-0.21-idmapdconf.patch
Patch6: librpcsecgss-0.19-bufoverflow.patch

Group: System Environment/Libraries
BuildRoot: %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-root
BuildRequires: pkgconfig, gettext, autoconf, automake, libtool
BuildRequires: libgssapi-devel >= 0.10, openldap-devel
Requires(postun): /sbin/ldconfig
Requires(pre): /sbin/ldconfig
Requires: libgssapi >= 0.10, openldap, nfs-utils >= 1.0.9-45

%description
Support libraries that are needed by the commands and
daemons the nfs-utils rpm.

%package devel
Summary: Development files for the nfs-utils-lib library
Group: Development/Libraries
Requires: %{name} = %{version}-%{release}
Requires: pkgconfig

%description devel
This package includes header files and libraries necessary for
developing programs which use the nfs-utils-lib library.

%prep
%setup -c -q -a1
mv %{libnfsidmap}-%{idmapvers} %{libnfsidmap}
mv %{librpcsecgss}-%{rpcsecgssvers} %{librpcsecgss}

%patch0 -p1
%patch1 -p1
%patch2 -p1
%patch3 -p1
%patch4 -p1
%patch5 -p1
%patch6 -p1

%build
top=`pwd`
for dir in %{libs} ; do
        pushd $dir
        [ -f ./autogen.sh ] && sh ./autogen.sh
        autoconf -I "$top"
        popd
done
for dir in %{libs} ; do
        pushd $dir
        %configure --prefix=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT
        popd
done
for dir in %{libs} ; do
        pushd $dir
        make all
        popd
done

%install
rm -rf %{buildroot}
for dir in %{libs} ; do
        pushd $dir
        DESTDIR=%{buildroot} make install
        popd
done

for dir in %{libs} ; do
        mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/%{_usr}/share/doc/$dir
        pushd $dir
        for file in AUTHORS ChangeLog NEWS README ; do
                install -m 755 $file $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_usr}/share/doc/$dir
        done
        popd
done
mkdir -p ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/etc
rm  ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_usr}/share/man/man5/idmapd.conf.5

%post -p /sbin/ldconfig

%postun -p /sbin/ldconfig

%clean
rm -rf %{buildroot}


%files
%defattr(-,root,root)

%{_libdir}/librpcsecgss.so.*
%{_libdir}/librpcsecgss.la

%{_libdir}/libnfsidmap*.so.*
%{_libdir}/libnfsidmap*.so

%{_defaultdocdir}/%{librpcsecgss}/AUTHORS
%{_defaultdocdir}/%{librpcsecgss}/ChangeLog
%{_defaultdocdir}/%{librpcsecgss}/NEWS
%{_defaultdocdir}/%{librpcsecgss}/README
%{_libdir}/pkgconfig/librpcsecgss.pc

%{_defaultdocdir}/%{libnfsidmap}/AUTHORS
%{_defaultdocdir}/%{libnfsidmap}/ChangeLog
%{_defaultdocdir}/%{libnfsidmap}/NEWS
%{_defaultdocdir}/%{libnfsidmap}/README
%{_libdir}/pkgconfig/libnfsidmap.pc
%{_mandir}/man3/nfs4_uid_to_name.3.gz

%files devel
%defattr(0644,root,root,755)
%{_libdir}/librpcsecgss.a
%{_libdir}/librpcsecgss.so
%{_includedir}/rpcsecgss/rpc/auth.h
%{_includedir}/rpcsecgss/rpc/auth_gss.h
%{_includedir}/rpcsecgss/rpc/svc.h
%{_includedir}/rpcsecgss/rpc/svc_auth.h
%{_includedir}/rpcsecgss/rpc/rpc.h
%{_includedir}/rpcsecgss/rpc/rpcsecgss_rename.h
%{_includedir}/nfsidmap.h
%{_libdir}/libnfsidmap*.a
%{_libdir}/libnfsidmap*.la

%changelog
* Mon Jan 16 2012 Steve Dickson <steved@redhat.com> 1.0.8-7.9
- Remove installation of man page and idmapd.conf (bz 782153)

* Wed Mar 10 2010 Steve Dickson <steved@redhat.com> 1.0.8-7.8
- Added the installation of the updated idmapd.conf file
  its man page (bz 502707)

* Wed Feb 10 2010 Steve Dickson <steved@redhat.com> 1.0.8-7.7
- Updated libnfsidmap to 0.21 (bz 502707)

* Tue Mar 3 2009 Jeff Layton <jlayton@redhat.com> 1.0.8-7.6
- libnfsidmap patch to handle ERANGE error on getgrnam_r (bz 453804)

* Wed Sep 26 2007 Steve Dickson <steved@redhat.com> 1.0.8-7.5
- Updated libnfsidmap to -17 to fix a security issue (bz 254042)

* Tue Sep 25 2007 Steve Dickson <steved@redhat.com> 1.0.8-7.4
-  Fixed RPC library buffer overflow (bz 265061)

* Fri Dec  1 2006 Steve Dickson <steved@redhat.com> 1.0.8-7.3
- Fixed typo in the package description (bz 218111)

* Wed Aug 30 2006 Steve Dickson <steved@redhat.com> 1.0.8-7.2
- added automake to BuildRequires:

* Wed Aug 30 2006 Steve Dickson <steved@redhat.com> 1.0.8-7.1
- rebuild

* Wed Aug  2 2006 Steve Dickson <steved@redhat.com> 1.0.8-7
- Updated librpcsecgss to -0.14

* Wed Jul 26 2006 Steve Dickson <steved@redhat.com> 1.0.8-6
- Added GSSLIBS to the linking of librpcsecgss (bz 198238)

* Wed Jul 12 2006 Jesse Keating <jkeating@redhat.com> - 1.0.8-5.1
- rebuild

* Tue Jun 20 2006 Steve Dickson <steved@redhat.com> 1.0.8-3.1
- Updated libnfsidmap and  librpcsecgss to latest upstream version

* Fri Feb 10 2006 Jesse Keating <jkeating@redhat.com> - 1.0.8-3.1
- bump again for double-long bug on ppc(64)

* Thu Feb 09 2006 Florian La Roche <laroche@redhat.com> 1.0.8-3
- remove empty scripts

* Tue Feb 07 2006 Jesse Keating <jkeating@redhat.com> - 1.0.8-2.1
- rebuilt for new gcc4.1 snapshot and glibc changes

* Thu Jan 19 2006 Steve Dickson <steved@redhat.com> 1.0.8-2
- Added debugging routines to libnfsidmap

* Fri Jan  6 2006 Steve Dickson <steved@redhat.com> 1.0.8-1
- Initial commit
```

My last step is to build the RPM
rpmbuild -ba nfs-utils-lib.spec

But it always fails with the message below, any ideas anyone what I am doing wrong?

**

```
**Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.98968
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/rpmbuild/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ LANG=C
+ export LANG
+ unset DISPLAY
+ cd /home/rpmbuild/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ rm -rf nfs-utils-lib-1.0.9
+ /bin/mkdir -p nfs-utils-lib-1.0.9
+ cd nfs-utils-lib-1.0.9
+ /bin/gzip -dc /home/rpmbuild/rpmbuild/SOURCES/libnfsidmap-0.21.tar.gz
+ tar -xf -
+ STATUS=0
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ /bin/gzip -dc /home/rpmbuild/rpmbuild/SOURCES/librpcsecgss-0.19.tar.gz
+ tar -xf -
+ STATUS=0
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
++ /usr/bin/id -u
+ '[' 525 = 0 ']'
++ /usr/bin/id -u
+ '[' 525 = 0 ']'
+ /bin/chmod -Rf a+rX,u+w,g-w,o-w .
+ mv libnfsidmap-0.21 libnfsidmap
+ mv librpcsecgss-0.19 librpcsecgss
+ echo 'Patch #0 (librpcsecgss-0.13-compile.patch):'
Patch #0 (librpcsecgss-0.13-compile.patch):
+ patch -p1 -s
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file librpcsecgss/src/Makefile.am.rej
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.98968 (%prep)**
```

**

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to apply a patch for `Makefile.am` in `librpcsecgss-0.13` to version `0.19`. And it's failing.

Comment: Thank you Aaron, im kind of puzzled on this one, would you know the proper steps to apply this patch?

Comment: Find out what the patch is for first. It is probably a bugfix that was applied upstream already (e.g. in `0.14`) and is now obsolete so just remove it from the `spec` file.

Comment: This is to address the following vulnerability on CentOS 5.10 done by PCI Scan.

Upgrade librpcsecgss to 0.15.
Estimated time: 2 hours
Download and apply the upgrade from: http://www.citi.umich.edu/projects/nfsv4/linux/librpcsecgss/
This will address 2 instances of the following issue: Kerberos "svcauth_gss_validate()" Buffer Overflow Vulnerability (kerberos-svc-authgss-
buffer-overflow).

The RPM package that needs to be updated with the latest librpcsecgss is: nfs-utils-lib-1.0.8-7.9.el5